# syntonly + float package : not compatible

Tags: floats, syntax-checker

I try to use `syntaxonly` + `float` package.

See the MWE

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\syntaxonly
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{carte}{h}{carte}
\floatname{carte}{Carte}
\begin{document}

\begin{carte}

        \includegraphics{something.png}
        \caption{s}
\end{carte}
\end{document}
```

If I comment `\syntaxonly`, I have no error (if the someting.png file exists, of course !). But the `\syntaxonly` which should check the syntax... makes syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. But instead of `syntonly` you can use the `-draftmode` option to `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{syntonly}
\syntaxonly
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{carte}{h}{carte}
\floatname{carte}{Carte}

\makeatletter
\ifsyntax@
  \let\fs@plain\@gobble
  \let\@float@setevery\@gobble
  \let\@fs@capt\relax
  \def\@endfloatbox#1\end@float{\end@float}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{carte}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\caption{s}
\end{carte}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that's working. I don't know which people should be informed of this incompatibility. I don't use pdflatex but xelatex, which seems to have no `-draftmode` or similar option (xelatex --help)

Comment: @Maïeul I'd say it's a problem of `newfloat`; I don't think `syntonly` can be deemed responsible for constructs that add to the kernel way of doing things.

Comment: yes, you are right. I will send an email to its author.